# Nodejs setTimeout Database Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my part of codes :

```
var nodePort = 3030;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('mysql');
var dbPool = db.createPool({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '1234',
    database : 'test',
    port : 3306
});


var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();
var sender = new gcm.Sender('API'); //Api Key
var registrationIds = [];

app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded() ); 

foo = function(){
  dbPool.getConnection(function(objErr, objConn){
    if(objErr){
        console.log('ERROR');
    }else{
        objConn.query("SELECT * FROM person", function(Err, Rows, Fields){
            for(var i=0; i<Rows.length; i++){
                console.log(Rows[i].Name);
            }
        });
    }
  });
  setTimeout(foo,1000);
}
foo();
app.listen(nodePort);
console.log('App listening on port' + nodePort);
```

[image]

This function runs only 10-time and stops, if i try to connect database . 
I want to check my database every second, are there any ways to do it?

Comment: what do you mean? Its not about gcm api-key. Also that api-key only for testing

Comment: i know its not about the api key, you should not post it publicly anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nodePort = 3030;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('mysql');
var dbPool = db.createPool({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '1234',
    database : 'test',
    port : 3306
});


var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();
var sender = new gcm.Sender('API'); //Api Key
var registrationIds = [];

app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded() ); 

foo = function(){
  dbPool.getConnection(function(objErr, objConn){
    if(objErr){
        console.log('ERROR');
    }else{
        objConn.query("SELECT * FROM person", function(Err, Rows, Fields){
            for(var i=0; i<Rows.length; i++){
                console.log(Rows[i].Name);
            }
        });
    }
  });
}
setInterval(function(){foo();},1000);

app.listen(nodePort);
console.log('App listening on port' + nodePort);
```

Comment: `setInterval(foo, 1000);`. No need to create a new scope.